# Can I create a Couchbase Lite index based on a concatenated string?

Tags: indexing, couchbase-lite

I have an app written for Couchbase Lite 1.4, and I'm upgrading it to 2.7.

We have a bunch of existing MapDelegate functions. I'm going to replace each of these with an Index and a Query.

In one method, we are creating the map based on a custom concatenated string:

```
                            dynamic items;
                            document.TryGetValue("items", out items);
                            if (items is JArray)
                            {
                                foreach (var item in items)
                                {
                                    string divisionCode = item.divisionCode;
                                    string styleSeasonCode = item.styleSeasonCode;
                                    int id = item.id;

                                    emit(string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}",
                                        divisionCode,
                                        styleSeasonCode,
                                        id
                                        ), item);
                                }
                            }
```

Is it possible to create an index based on a custom concatenated string like this? Or will we have to change the document so that DivisionCode, StyleSeasonCode, and Id are top-level fields, instead of being inside the array?

Comment: I don't think this question makes sense, as posed.  You can't create an index on "foo_bar_baz" because there is no property named "foo_bar_baz".  Actually, I suppose, technically, you could create such an index.  Since there is no such property, though, it would be pretty useless...

Comment: I have discovered the ArrayFunction and ArrayExpression classes in CouchbaseLite, but I'm still not sure how to use them to recreate the index. For each object in the array, it creates a new index value.